# How to access the same code parts inside Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When I select a particular code base inside Visual Studio, VS is smart enough to find the same code parts inside a currently open document.

Is there a shortcut or a key combination which allows me to process all these snippet at once, for example to change all of them?

In the image below, I have selected Task-ResponseDto.

In the image the middle occurrence, surrounded with red circle is selected, but two additional occurrences were marked as well.
Is there any way to change them all, without opening the Find/Replace box?

[image]

Comment: I think you are showing one of the highlighting features and that doesn't select the text for edit. But one of the refactoring features may help.

Comment: Probably the easiest thing to do is do a multi-line cursor selection, highlight all three of them, and change them to what you want. https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8hcm.gif

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Is it possible to activate multi-line cursor on the selections that are not vertically align?